LocalAddress setup for reactor-netty client and server
Cant find the way to setup local transport for reactor-netty client and server
I've tried to simply provide bindAddress as LocalAdress("some") but has no luck with
java.nio.channels.UnsupportedAddressTypeException

Also was trying to provide runOn(DefaultEventLoopGroup) but got
java.lang.IllegalStateException: channel not registered to an event loop

UPD: assume to have smth like this
fun handle(requests: Flux<Request>) : Flux<Response> {
    val responses = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer<Response>()
    ReactorLocalClient.create()
        .bindAddress { LocalAddress("proxy") }
        .doOnConnected {
            // configure pipeline handlers
        }
        .handle { inbound, outbound ->
            requests.flatMap { outbound.sendObject(it) }.subscribe()
            inbound.receiveObject().doOnNext { responses.tryEmitNext(it) }.then()
        }
    return responses.asFlux()
}

Server side should have the same possibilities

please provide some example and explain what you want to achieve

@VioletaGeorgieva i was thinking about creating local transport using Reactor netty server bind to LocalAddress and Reactor netty client connected to this LocalAddress within same service codebase.
If we are talking abour plain Netty client-server bootstrapping we can achive such kind of setup.

I want to achive reuse of existing netty channel configuration, but want to use them as the local adapter for business logic

We might need change something in Reactor Netty in order to achieve your use case, because of this I was asking for example

@VioletaGeorgieva updated the question
